# Python development - unexpected indent problem

Tags: python, django

I have recently inserted an if statement into some previously working code. I now get an unexpected indent error when I run it on the start of my if statement.

```
   ImpressionsBasedOnWeight = setImpressionsBasedOnWeight(setImpressionsBasedOnWeightData)
   impressions = data[2]
       if reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers > weighted_impressions:
           users = weighted_impressions
       else:
           users = reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers
   Pages_in_thousands = impressions / 1000
```

If I remove the indent it fails saying it expects an indent and if I then add the indent it fails saying unexpected indent...

Answer (score 6):

`impressions = data[2]` is a simple assigment. There should be no change of the indentation afterwards. So you need to have `impressions = ..` and `if ..` with the same indentation:

```
ImpressionsBasedOnWeight = setImpressionsBasedOnWeight(setImpressionsBasedOnWeightData)
impressions = data[2]
if reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers > weighted_impressions:
    users = weighted_impressions
else:
    users = reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers
Pages_in_thousands = impressions / 1000
```

Also, make sure you're not switching between tabs and spaces for indentation. You can set some indicators to display symbols for tabs, and a good editor should unify indentation when you select the whole code, press `Tab` and then `Shift+Tab`.

Answer (score 2):

Why to put if with indent?

```
   ImpressionsBasedOnWeight = setImpressionsBasedOnWeight(setImpressionsBasedOnWeightData)
   impressions = data[2]
   if reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers > weighted_impressions:
       users = weighted_impressions
   else:
       users = reportSuite.RP_UniqueUsers
   Pages_in_thousands = impressions / 1000
```